# Are most foreign jobs only open to those already have permission to work?

Tags: job-search, work-environment, hiring-process, recruitment, visa

In job listings on stackoverflow ,I see so many foreign jobs  where **Visa Sponsor** is written.

But I have read some where that most foreign jobs are only open to those who  already have permission to work in that country.Very few job openings are there which are available to those in need of a work permit.How true is that?

So everywhere where **Visa Sponsor** is written in StackOverflow jobs are they really open to those who doesn't have work permit.And will those companies help to provide Visa to work in their country?

Comment: Depends on the job, the company, industry, country, country of origin, ease of obtaining work visas, profile of the applicant and so on and so forth. There's no one answer to this and even if there were general statistics they would be largely meaningless for your own job search. (VTC)

Answer (score 2):

The rules vary by country but generally getting a visa/work permit (different countries use different terminology) for a foreign worker is a slow and beauracractic process that is not gauranteed to succeed. In many situations there is also a legal requirement to preffer candidates who already have the right to work freely in the country.

So in most cases even if the company is in general prepared to sponsor visas/work permits they are unlikely to do so unless you are significantly better than the candidates who already have the right to work freely in the country.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if the say they are willing to sponsor a Visa then the answer is yes when the right person comes along.

How much to sponsor a person for a Visa? Not a lot in terms of costs of recruitment.

Comment: And if a company sponsor's someone for visa then is there guaranty that embassy will provide Visa to that person if he has qualifications and required work experience?

Comment: It is not a done deal. Criminal records etc. But it does help the process a lot. Basically countries want people that are qualified, going to pay their tax man and not cause hassle. Also those people cannot be found easily in their own country

Comment: "those people cannot be found easily in their own country"..Does that mean with that people with good skills and who are qualified?

Comment: A company wanting X, Y, Z skills that are rare might have to justify why they need to employ a person from overseas. This depends on the nation. Usually when the say they can sponsor a Visa application they are quite confident they can do this.

Comment: Thanku for ur time..what are other good sites where i can find visa sponsor jobs?

Comment: I do not know. Not into that game.